# Is it a bad practice to query remote resources inside validation?

Tags: design-patterns, php, domain-driven-design, validation, rules-and-constraints

Watching [this talk about Symfony Forms and validation, at 23:06](https://youtu.be/MyGlUAvyIrs?t=1386), I got stuck with a doubt
I couldn't find a satisfying answer to:

**Is it a bad practice to execute a query (or a web request, or a side effect in general) inside a validator?**

In my case, I have either *Symfony Validation Constraints* and some implementation of the *Specification Pattern*.

I am wondering how bad it is to perform queries to the database into these validation elements, given the fact that they could be used multiple times in the same controller (or in the same form, in the case of using Symfony components).

- there's a **performance concern**; especially in case the request into the validation is always the same and there's no real reason to send it multiple times.
- there's a **failure concern**; what if the response is delayed or, even worse, the request fails?

  - should the validation add an incident/violation because it wasn't able to ensure that the data is actually valid (even in the case where it actually is) and report it together with the other incidents/violations ?
  - should it accept it instead because of the impossibility to validate?
  - should it try again?
  - should it throw an error?
- there's a boundaries crossing and lack of **separation of concerns**; I would not expect that anything from the Domain Model (IMHO, including its invariants/validation-rules) knows about or has dependencies on anything from the Infrastructure (the persistence layer in this case).

Is it acceptable? Should it be avoided? Is it totally fine?
I generally have a feeling of rejection in doing that (and that's why I am asking).

Comment: You are using the term '[side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))' here but I don't think you mean it in the standard way.  What that usually means is that you are changing some sort of persistent state.  Queries against a DB don't usually fall into that category.  Are you really just asking about queries?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't quite sure about query as side-effect, but in my case I'm curious about *any operation that crosses the boundaries of the Domain Model*; specifically in the context of DDD. –  For how I see it, a constraint (an example might be *"the model 'email' field has an address that already exists or that was banned"*) is part of the Domain Logic and shouldn't know anything about the infrastructure (DB or validation services). That, to me, looks like the same reason for not executing queries inside the Model but demand it to the Repository (that has the responsibility to query the DBAL).

Comment: Btw, the video link points to the sentence where it starts to talk about making web requests inside a validation constraint. Maybe listening to it (10 secs are enough) could clarify what I mean (or what I... ugh.. felt ).

Comment: The "bounded context" paragraph of [this article](http://www.kamilgrzybek.com/design/domain-model-validation/) also explains what I mean (and makes the same email example! ).

Comment: The reason I am making the distinction is that if you really mean side-effects, I think the answer is: "probably bad practice" but for 'safe' queries, I'm in agreement with Telastyn.

Answer (score 4):

It should be strongly avoided (for the reasons you mention), but is sometimes better than the alternatives. Where necessary, it's really common to make a (local) cache to mitigate the performance concerns and to decrease the failure concerns.

Comment: An illustrative example: to know if a certificate is good, we need to check a CRL which means reaching out to a remote resource.  In order to address the challenges with this the concept of certificate stapling was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The reason is simple. It is *always* possible for the caller (service) of the validation component (model) to issue a query for the appropriate data and pass it as a parameter instead of having the validation component (model) send the query itself.

For example:

```
public function validateData($database, $dataId)
{
    $data = $database->getData($dataId);
    // do validation
}
```

can be refactored to:

```
// caller is responsible for getting data

public function validateData($data)
{
    // do validation
}
```

The upside of this (aside from the obvious testing implications) is that, because it pushes data retrieval as "high" as possible in your application, it allows for better optimization of querying/caching. Say the caller intends to validate two pieces of data. It may be possible to issue a single query, parse the response into the appropriate slices of data, and pass each to the corresponding validation component.

Comment: This assumes you trust the client.

Comment: @JimmyJames Of course your model provides a contract in the form of an interface.

Comment: Not sure how that is relevant.  A contract doesn't form a trust relationship.  For example, it would be a bad idea to accept pricing and discount data from a client on a retail website.

Comment: @JimmyJames The scope of the question at hand implies the "client" (a word I have not used) of the validation component is the very same system. I suspect OP can trust his or her own code. In any case, my answer is to be understood in terms  of design. Trust boundaries are not relevant to the question or my answer.

Comment: How is that implied?  Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @JimmyJames Sorry, I was being charitable towards your view point. The OP explicitly states that these validation components are used within a controller. They also make numerous references to DDD and make no mention of trust boundaries or “clients”. If you have a question about how to implement a service layer above a domain model, please post your own thread. I’d be happy to answer. The question above is how to implement the *model*.

Comment: I was looking at this in more general terms but sure, that makes sense.  I'm unsure of this advice in that context.  It would seem to introduce a lot of coupling in that the caller needs to know what the validation component needs to do it's job.

Comment: @JimmyJames It also reduces coupling by alleviating the model of any responsibility regarding persistence (and all of the problems IO introduces). When you hear the phrase "separation of concerns", *this* is to what it is referring -- drawing boundaries around modules and using interfaces to promote loose coupling. My answer said another way: The routine that answers the question , "Where does this data come from?" does not need to be the same routine that answers, "Is this data valid?". Here I invoke yet another commonly cited expression, "A function should only do one thing and do it well".

Comment: If you look at the video (the OP queued up the link to the exact right point) the context given is validating an address against a remote service.  What exactly are you proposing would be passed to the validator in this case to avoid calling the service?

Comment: @JimmyJames The question OP is asking is *not* about the specific situation in the video (although this is the impetus). They are very clearly asking about the general usefulness of issuing queries (invoking I/O) within a domain model as it relates to "separation of concerns", "performance", and "failure concern". The answer I have provided optimizes for the above criteria. You are asking a different question. Again, you are free to create a thread and formalize your thoughts. I would happy to answer any questions you have in the appropriate forum.

Comment: I don't think you are answering the question.  As I understand it, the OP is asking about accessing additional data or processing using a remote resource needed to validate data in process.  You seem to be talking about retrieving the data that is being validated.

Comment: @JimmyJames You are misunderstanding the question and my answer. To be clear the answer to the question, "How do I integrate remote validation into my domain?" is, "You cannot". It must be lifted outside the domain because, by definition, rules that cannot be enforced by the domain are not part of it. The appropriate implementation would be to implement this kind of I/O in the service layer (the caller in my example). In this case it would be useful to modify our understanding of  what `$data` represents (maybe it is of type `ValidatedAddress`).

Comment: It's the OPs example from a video about Symfony validators in a question about Symfony validators that references address validation in a remote service from a Symfony validator.  Your stance is that none of that is relevant to the question?

Comment: @JimmyJames My understanding of the question, given the totality of the language used in combination with the topics tagged and the ensuing comments, is, again, that the OP is asking about the *general* practice of including I/O within the domain to enforce an invariant. The example involving Symphony is used to illustrate the problem, not define it. I could just as easily synthesize a different example of the same problem (which I have done in my answer above). If you find my answer insufficient or unsatisfactory, you are free to compose your own. I stand behind the approach I outline above.

Comment: @JimmyJames It's important to understand that the difference between "using a remote resource to validate data" and "retrieving the data that is being validated" is only a matter of semantics. Instead of `$isValid =  $resource->verifyAddress($data)`, the same thing could be modeled as `$address = $resource->fetchValidAddress($data)`. Can you see how this applies to my answer?

Comment: So again what exactly is the caller passing to the validator in the case of the address validation case?  You said this is *always* possible.  If you are using a 3rd party proprietary address validation service, what is the caller retrieving to pass to the validator?

Comment: @JimmyJames As my answer clearly states, the result of the query to the service. There is more than one way to model it. Are you supposing the service does not return a result?

Answer (score 1):

I agreed. I have the same feeling of rejection when it comes to calling external services. How @Telastyn say, some times is necessary so worth doing a bit of research to meet in deep the tools and the alternatives at hand.

@Telastyn also mentioned caches. In line with his argument, I suggest meeting your tools first because some of them implement cache out of the box. It's the case of DB drivers, WWW architecture, ERM, frameworks, etc.

For example

`given the fact that they could be used multiple times`

Research whether your DB, driver, ERM or framework is already caching statements. If they do, many of the validation queries will be cached eventually. For a while. The same applies to HTTP requests (if you set the proper headers).

However, working with caches can be painful, overall if we don't understand how, when and what is invalidated.

Regarding  *performance*, often we put the focus on it too soon. Start implementing first the easiest solution, perform load tests and get real metrics. Then you will be in a better position to make decisions because these will be ground and backed by data.

To finish, when it comes to *communication failures*, worth knowing patterns and strategies. For example Circuit Breaker, Retry or Fail Fast. These won't save you from the Fallacies of the Distributed Computing, but they can keep the actual solution simple and reliable.

Summarising, if you can avoid it, then do it. If you can't, start with meeting your resources at hand, implement something simple and test it. Then look for enhancements or alternatives if need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have code that queries some resource, and eventually either returns a validated result, or some error. Usually this will be asynchronous.

If it is asynchronous then it is no problem at all to do the query, and then the validation does another query. For the user of the code, it makes no difference.

The problem is that you have twice the latency. So if you know that the resource you need for validation is always needed, and you know which resource is needed, then it would be more efficient but slightly more complicated to do both queries simultaneously, and produce the validated result when both resources arrive.

There may be situations where you have no choice. Let's say you query a customer number, and then for the validation you must check whether the customer doesn't owe you more than £1,000. Since you don't know the customer number ahead, the validation must wait to query the information about the customer until the customer number is known. It's not nice, but you do what you need to do.

PS. No need to be afraid that a query needed for validation could fail. You will be making two requests - for the data, and for things you need to validate it. Each could fail, but it's unlikely. Just report each failure as a failure. Don't say "here's the data, but I couldn't verify it", say "your request for validated data failed". (And usually failures are not random, but due to some problem somewhere along the line. If your first query succeeded, then you know your internet connection is fine, the DNS server is alive, and the server hasn't crashed, so the query for validation is much more likely to succeed).